# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException in Monitor class of dining philosophers

Tags: java, exception, condition-variable, monitors

I am new to monitors and condition variables. I am using lock and condition variables in my monitor.

```
public class Monitor  
{   
    private final int piNumberOfPhilosophers;
    private PhilosopherCard[] self;
    private Integer[] names;
    private int invited = 0;
    static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition[] status; // = lock.newCondition();
    private String[] state;
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Monitor(int piNumberOfPhilosophers)
    {        this.piNumberOfPhilosophers = piNumberOfPhilosophers;         

        self = new PhilosopherCard[this.piNumberOfPhilosophers];
        names = new Integer[this.piNumberOfPhilosophers];
        status = new Condition [this.piNumberOfPhilosophers];
        state = new String [this.piNumberOfPhilosophers];
        //Arrays.asList(state).indexOf(4);      
        }

    public void invitePhilosopher (int id){

        names[invited] = id;
        System.out.println(invited);
        PhilosopherCard philosopher = new PhilosopherCard("thinking");
        self[invited] = philosopher;
        status[invited] =lock.newCondition();
        state[invited] = "thinking";
        invited++;
        }           
    /**
     * check other philosophers (<_<) - > (0_o) -> (>_>)
     */

    private void  test (int index){
        lock.lock();

        int left = index-1;
        int right = index +1;
        if(index==0){
            left=piNumberOfPhilosophers-1;
        }
        if(index == piNumberOfPhilosophers-1){
            right = 0;
        }
        if((state[left]!="eating")&(state[right]!="eating")){
            state[index]="eating";
            status[index].signal();
            }
        lock.unlock();

    }


    public void pickUp(final int piTID) throws InterruptedException
    {        
        int index = Arrays.asList(names).indexOf(piTID);    
        state[index]="hungry";
        test(index);
        if(!state[index].equals("eating")){     
                status[index].wait();
        }   
    }

    /**
     * When a given philosopher's done eating, they put the chopstiks/forks down
     * and let others know they are available.
     */
    public void putDown(final int piTID)
    {   
        int index = Arrays.asList(names).indexOf(piTID);
        self[index].setState("thinking");

        int left = index-1;
        int right = index +1;
        if(index==0){
            left=piNumberOfPhilosophers-1;
        }
        if(index == piNumberOfPhilosophers-1){
            right = 0;
        }
        test(left);
        test(right);

        // ...
    }


}
```

In putdown we can self[index].signal to wake up monitors. But it is not that important. And, in pick up method monitor exception occurs, when we use wait on condition variable. Why? Because they all use 1 lock? 
All trace

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at Monitor.pickUp(Monitor.java:75)
    at Philosopher.run(Philosopher.java:95)
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at Monitor.pickUp(Monitor.java:75)
    at Philosopher.run(Philosopher.java:95)
```

I updated the code and removed extra class, so all in one class, maybe now it is more clear where can be that error

Comment: please give the full stacktrace of the exception, that's generally a nice first step in debugging

Comment: Don't mix synchronization and `java.util.concurrent.` That way madness lies.

Comment: yeah, but it doenst work anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things you're doing wrong.

1. You are `synchronizing` on `this` and not locking on `PhilosopherCard.lock`. By locking, I mean `PhilosopherCard.lock.lock();`
2. You are using `wait` instead of `await`.

---

Update for more information

If you take a look at this code of yours and remove `synchronized` the code won't fail.

```
   private void test (int index){
        PhilosopherCard.lock.lock();
        int left = index-1;
        int right = index +1;
        if(index==0){
            left=piNumberOfPhilosophers-1;
        }
        if(index == piNumberOfPhilosophers-1){
            right = 0;
        }
        if((state[left]!="eating")&(state[right]!="eating")){
            state[index]="eating";
            status[index].signal();;
            }
        PhilosopherCard.lock.unlock();
    }
```

Where you `signal` it is similar to `await`, but without synchronized why wouldn't it throw an IMSE?  That's because you are holding the 
`PhilosopherCard.lock` lock.  If you removed those two locks you would get an IMSE.

You are running into that issue in `pickUp`.  I would remove `synchronized` from the method all together.  Why?  Because you are mixing synchronization.  If you want to do synchronization with `synchronized` that's fine, but if you're doing synchronization with `java.util.concurrent.Lock` then you cannot use `synchronized`.

The `synchronized` keyword can allow you to use `wait`, `notify` and `notifyAll` on the object.

The `j.u.c.Lock` and `j.u.c.Condition` allow you to use `await`, `signal`, `signalAll`.  So my suggestion is either use only `Lock`/`Condition` or `synchronized`.  Not both.

Comment: If you do (1) before signaling, it will work correctly.

Comment: He's right, conditons require await(). But to make the IllegalMonitorStateException go away, you'll need to synchronize on the proper object first.

Comment: @flup Using `PhilosopherCard.lock.lock();` will do the synchronizing the OP needs

Comment: You're right, I thought the question was about synchronized/wait but it's more about lock() and await().

Comment: i removed philosopher card, all in one class, maybe now it is more obvious what can it be/

Comment: @Ophelia I know what the problem is but am trying to give you enough information to come to the conclusion on your own.  I'll edit my answer to give more information.

Comment: that is correct, i dont really  need synchronization there. but if remove that i still have this:Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.signal(Unknown Source)
 at Monitor.test(Monitor.java:67)
 at Monitor.pickUp(Monitor.java:81)
 at Philosopher.run(Philosopher.java:95)

Comment: @Ophelia Did you remove `synchronized` or `PhilosopherCard.lock.lock();`

Comment: @Ophelia can you update your code in the question to how it is now?

Comment: @Ophelia Sorry, just got back to it.  Glad you got it working.  Do you have any questions from this point on from what you finished with?